# Why does this Jquery function appear to do nothing

Tags: jquery

```
ApplyClickableLinkToClass = function(selectedElements) {
// Go through each of the passed in selections and try to apply a link to them
$.each(selectedElements, function() {
    var linkElement = $("a:first:not(.do-not-apply-clickable-link)", $(this));
    var link = linkElement.attr("href");
    if (!IsNullEmptyOrUndefined(link)) {
        $(this).click(function(firstLink) {
            var divToLink = firstLink;
            return function() {
                $(divToLink).unbind('click');
                if (divToLink.attr("target") != "_blank") {
                    window.location = link;
                    return false;
                }
            };
        }(linkElement));
    }
});
```

}

I would think it would open target in new window and remove click event but does nothing when called, any ideas ?

Called as follows

```
    var clickable = function () {
    ApplyClickableLinkToClass($j(".rc_blueBtn, .rc_whiteBtn:not(.More)"));
    };
    setTimeout(clickable, 2000);
```

Comment: Three questions about the same piece of code. Looks funny.

Comment: 162 questions and 5 answers... while there's no requirement to answer other peoples questions, being part of a community is a give and take.  I'd suggest giving a little more..

Comment: "a:first:not(.do-not-apply-clickable-link)" just doesnt seems right to me. "a:not(.do-not-apply-clickable-link):first" should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

there is any reason why you have used $j() insted of simple $() selector in your function call ?

```
ApplyClickableLinkToClass($j(".rc_blueBtn, .rc_whiteBtn:not(.More)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).one("click", function() {
```

its easily do all you need add click for one time only , then remove automatically.